# Javascript - why regular expression replace not working for loops?

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

I'm trying to replace following patterns using regular expressions.

```
function get_table_name(table_partition_name) {
  var result = table_partition_name;
  const atQueryRegex = "[@].*"
  result = result.replace(atQueryRegex, "")

  const uuid64Regex   = /_?[a-f0-9]{64}/i;
  const uuid32Regex   = /_?[a-f0-9]{8}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{4}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{4}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{4}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{12}/i;
  const uuid24Regex   = /_?[a-f0-9]{24}/i;
  const mmyyyyRegex   = /_?[0-9]{2}__mm_[0-9]{2}_yyyy_[0-9]{4}/i;
  const flowridaRegex = /_?5000y00001[a-z0-9]{8}/i;
  const timeRegex     = /_?[0-9]{4,8}t?[0-9_]*/i;
  const numRegex      = /_?[0-9]+[0-9_]*(_|$)/i;
  const tsReplacement = "_*";
  const tsRegexes = [
      uuid64Regex,
      uuid32Regex,
      uuid24Regex,
      mmyyyyRegex,
      flowridaRegex,
      timeRegex,
      numRegex
  ];
  for (const expr of tsRegexes) {
      result = result.replace(expr, tsReplacement);
      console.log(expr);
      console.log(result);
  }
  
  return result
}

test = "DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__31259_f3e3ec7e0f54b96d0d26c7fe_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_bcce6842c5acde4a0d0b232f_6_7_cumulative_20220802_20220808"
console.log(get_table_name(test))
```

However, the final result is `DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__**_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_bcce6842c5acde4a0d0b232f_*cumulative_20220802_20220808`; while `DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__**_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_*_*cumulative_*` is expected.

**When looking thru all the printed output, some regular expressions are not functioning as expected, as marked in the red box. However, when I tried that specific expression it does work.**

[image]

Here is how the single test would work:

```
test = "DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__**_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_bcce6842c5acde4a0d0b232f_*cumulative_20220802_20220808"

console.log(test.replace(/_?[a-f0-9]{24}/i, "_*"))
```

Result:

```
DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__**_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_*_*cumulative_20220802_20220808
```

Comment: Have you verified that the `uuid32` regular expression is not matching first?

Comment: _"However, when I tried that specific expression it does work"_ Did try the specific expression on the string right above it or on the original string? The problem with iterative substitution is that you need to take into account how the string produced by previous substitution(s) would look like. Otherwise, you end up with unexpected results.

Comment: It would be much more useful if you'd post the *actual* output as text, and not an image. And have you checked for possible special characters in your source text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uuid24Regex` matches two times. At first for `_f3e3ec7e0f54b96d0d26c7fe` and then again for `_bcce6842c5acde4a0d0b232f`. The third iteration of the loop (processing `uuid24Regex`) only replaces the first match which you used in your test. By testing manually (outside of the loop) you replaced the second match.

In order to replace both occurrences within the loop you have to use [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll). The regular expressions then must have the global flag (g) set. (e.g. `/_?[a-f0-9]{64}/gi`).

The following code snippet results in the string you expect:

```text
DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__**_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_*_*cumulative_*
```

```js
function get_table_name(table_partition_name) {
  var result = table_partition_name;
  const atQueryRegex = "[@].*"
  result = result.replace(atQueryRegex, "")

  const uuid64Regex   = /_?[a-f0-9]{64}/gi;
  const uuid32Regex   = /_?[a-f0-9]{8}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{4}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{4}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{4}(-|_)?[a-f0-9]{12}/gi;
  const uuid24Regex   = /_?[a-f0-9]{24}/gi;
  const mmyyyyRegex   = /_?[0-9]{2}__mm_[0-9]{2}_yyyy_[0-9]{4}/gi;
  const flowridaRegex = /_?5000y00001[a-z0-9]{8}/gi;
  const timeRegex     = /_?[0-9]{4,8}t?[0-9_]*/gi;
  const numRegex      = /_?[0-9]+[0-9_]*(_|$)/gi;
  const tsReplacement = "_*";
  const tsRegexes = [
      uuid64Regex,
      uuid32Regex,
      uuid24Regex,
      mmyyyyRegex,
      flowridaRegex,
      timeRegex,
      numRegex
  ];
  for (const expr of tsRegexes) {
      result = result.replaceAll(expr, tsReplacement);
      console.log(expr);
      console.log(result);
  }
  
  return result
}

test = "DWEB_UI_ROLLOUT__31259_f3e3ec7e0f54b96d0d26c7fe_snap_direct_snap_replay_view_event_user_bcce6842c5acde4a0d0b232f_6_7_cumulative_20220802_20220808"
console.log(get_table_name(test))
```